# How to add all the elements inside loop in Python?

Tags: python

For some reason I want this:

```
a = ['ok.py', 'hello.py']
```

I want to calculate size of each elements and add all those sizes and store in a single variable:

```
for i in a:
        dest = '/home/zurelsoft/my_files'
        fullname = os.path.join(dest, i) #Get the file_full_size to calculate size
        st = int(os.path.getsize(fullname))
        f_size = size(st)
```

It does this for every element. How can I add them all?

Comment: Am i missing something here, or why are you not just adding the size(st)s to the f_size instead of just inserting the value? fsize += size(st) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one method would be to add them to a list and then use `sum`

```
sizes = []
for i in a:
        dest = '/home/zurelsoft/my_files'
        fullname = os.path.join(dest, i) #Get the file_full_size to calculate size
        st = int(os.path.getsize(fullname))
        f_size = size(st)
        sizes.append(f_size)
print sum(sizes)
```

or you could have a single variable.

```
sum_size = 0
for i in a:
        dest = '/home/zurelsoft/my_files'
        fullname = os.path.join(dest, i) #Get the file_full_size to calculate size
        st = int(os.path.getsize(fullname))
        sum_size += size(st)
print sum_size
```

or you could keep it in a dictionary....

```
d = {}
for i in a:
        dest = '/home/zurelsoft/my_files'
        fullname = os.path.join(dest, i) #Get the file_full_size to calculate size
        st = int(os.path.getsize(fullname))
        d[i] = size(st)
```

to get each ones size:

```
print '\n'.join(['%s: %d' % (k, v) for k, v in d.items()])
```

to get the sum:

```
print sum(d.values())
```

wrapping it all into a function and using a method similar to the one used by [Ivo van der Wijk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14624538/1561176):

```
def get_file_sizes(parent_dir, files):
    import os
    return sum([os.path.getsize(os.path.join(parent_dir, f)) for f in files])
```

calling the function:

```
a = ['ok.py', 'hello.py']
all_sizes = get_file_sizes('/home/zurelsoft/my_files', a)
```

Comment: I am trying to adopt the first one: I get this error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: the error is not in the code i provided, that error means you are trying to use `+` between a `str` and an `int` there is not even an `+` operator in the code i wrote. maybe you mean the second one. in which case, it means that `size()` does not return a number, so you should change `size()` to return a number, or cast with `int()`

Comment: @InbarRose your code have `+` operator, in the `sum` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce it to a single sum with generator as follows:

```
sum(os.path.getsize(os.path.join("/etc", f)) for f in ["passwd", "hosts"])
```

Basically combining the individual steps you're taking into a single expression that can be passed to sum()

I'm not sure what size() does but you can of course insert that into the expression. Make sure it returns integers and not strings, of course.

Comment: only, where did you get `/etc`, `passwd` and `hosts` from? i don't think these paths help the OP. but the answer is indeed correct. dont forget the `import os`. i would use a dictionary to also store the size for each one. :)

Comment: I assume he's smart enough to figure out what /etc, passwd and hosts are in this case. I'm providing a sample that works for everyone (with a decent OS ;) in general.